# How can I create an installer for a WPF application as well as a ASP.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, visual-studio, installation

I have a Visual Studio 2017 project that contains a WPF application and a ASP.net application that interact through a database.

I am currently using [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects#overview) to create an installer for the entire project.

The problem I'm having is that I can successfully create an installer for the WPF application, but not the ASP.net application. Is there a way I can create an installer that installs both applications on a separate computer?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need an installer fopr a Web application?  You don't want to run that on the same PC as the WPF, right?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, I do want them to run on the same PC. The WPF is for networking and database related information and the web app is the interface for the user

Comment: Better be clearer about your hosting details etc. I still think it's a very strange setup. And that's why you don't find ready to roll tools.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I agree, it's a little strange, how do you normally publish a web application?

Comment: To a server. Like a Hosting provider, Azure. Or maybe on-premise. That's why I asked for more details.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It would have to be directly on the clients computer

Comment: @GreenSaber, Do you resolve this issue now? Do you want to deploy your app to your local IIS directly? Or you could think about using the WIX installer for your web app: https://alonam.com/blog/2016/09/14/creating_a_wix_installer_for_asp.net_web_applications.html and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I haven't resolved this problem yet. I think I want to install the web app directly to a computer but I'm not familiar with how the technology works or how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you have to choose a tool or set of tools to generate an installer for your projects to be deployed in your users'/consumers' computers. There are lots of available options. Some are free, some are paid (and quite expensive).

Free ones include [WiX Toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/) and [InstallForge](https://installforge.net/). Paid ones tend to be a lot easier to use and offer more ready-to-use features, and examples of these are [InstallShield](https://www.flexera.com/products/installation/installshield.html) and [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/).

I personally use WiX, as it offers quite interesting features, it is free, and has a huge comunity. On the other hand, its learning curve can be quite steep, depending on your specific needs.

Many other options are available. For a simpler (although much less flexible) solution for WinForms and WPF projects, check out [ClickOnce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce).

Comment: None of this addresses installing a web app. WiX may be able to do it, but you don't show how.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try Inno Setup: http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php